# Invoke a shell script from Java code

Tags: java, multithreading, unix, process

I want to invoke a shell script from java. It can be done with  Runtime.exec method. But the problem is the shell script will take around 3-4 hours to execute and its not advisable to apply Process.waitFor() for such a long process as it will keep the current thread in waiting state for 4 hours. This will happen in multithreaded environment where several java threads will be invoking multiple shell scripts, each consuming more than 3 hours. (although the number of threads will be small)

How can I make it asynchronous so that my java process doesn't have to wait and somehow it gets to know when the shell script finishes. I don't have an option to use JMS.

Kindly suggest a robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Callable` and `Future` to launch your script asynchronously and you can wait for it in separate thread

Comment: Yes thats true but again my question was is it advisable to wait for such a long time taking process? Can't it be truely asynchronous?

Comment: No-If you are certain you don't need to care once you launch it, Yes- If you need to do something on completion or handle exception that it may raise

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like

```
class AsyncProcessRunner {

    class AsyncProcess implements Runnable {
        String cmd;
        int rc;
        String out;
        String err;

        AsyncProcess(String cmd) {
            this.cmd = cmd;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run process here
            processEnded(this);
        }
    }

    void processEnded(AsyncProcess p) {
        // process termination
    }

    public void runAsync(String cmd) {
        new Thread(new AsyncProcess(cmd)).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is the shell script will take around 3-4 hours to execute and its not advisable to apply Process.waitFor() for such a long process as it will keep the current thread in waiting state for 4 hours. This will happen in multithreaded environment where several java threads will be invoking multiple shell scripts, each consuming more than 3 hours. (although the number of threads will be small)

To be honest, I think that the problem you are trying to solve is largely imaginary.

The cost of a single thread that waits for 4 hours doing nothing is next nothing.  It is the cost of using (typically) 1Mb of non-heap space to represent a stack.  And if the number of these threads is going to be small, then the total space is a small number of megabytes.  Unless you are running on a memory constrained system, it is not even worth worrying about.  (It is stretch to call it *"not advisable"* ... IMO).

And if your memory *is* constrained, then the first thing to try would be to allocate the threads with a reduced stack size; e.g. use [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.ThreadGroup,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String,%20long%29).  I think that 10Kb thread stacks would be sufficient for this task.